# Apply retry to each and every endpoint in the spring webflux application

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have created below webclient and using it inside of my service to make HTTP third party calls.

```
@Configuration
public class WebclientConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        // custom client connector with connection pool disabled is being used as by default the connection pooling is done and connection reset happens after some idle time.

        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.newConnection()))
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and in my service, I am calling the third party service like below.

```
private Flux<BusinessObject> getBusinessObjects(String serviceURL) {
        return this.webClient.get()
                .uri(serviceURL)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(BusinessObject.class)    //code below this, do I have to copy for each webclient request to configure the retry, even if the values are same
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.of(2, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                .doBeforeRetry((value) -> log.info("Retrying request " + value))
                .filter(error -> error instanceof WebClientRequestException)
                .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) ->
                        new RuntimeException(retrySignal.failure().getMessage())));

    }
```

My question is as in comment in above code.
I have multiple webclient calls, but I want to configure the retry backoff configuration at a single place. How can I do that? so that my code should look like below

```
private Flux<BusinessObject> getBusinessObjects(String serviceURL) {
            return this.webClient.get()
                    .uri(serviceURL)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(BusinessObject.class)
                    .somCommonRetryCodeWrappingTheRetryLogic();

                    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` operator for this purpose:

```java
private Flux<BusinessObject> getBusinessObjects(String serviceURL) {
        return this.webClient.get()
                .uri(serviceURL)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(BusinessObject.class)
                .transform(originalFlux -> wrapWithRetry(originalFlux));

}

private <T> Flux<T> wrapWithRetry(Flux<T> originalFlux) {
    return originalFlux
        .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.of(2, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
            .doBeforeRetry((value) -> log.info("Retrying request " + value))
            .filter(error -> error instanceof WebClientRequestException)
            .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) ->
                new RuntimeException(retrySignal.failure().getMessage())));
}
```

Only drawback is that if you have `Mono` use cases as well then you need to implement it twice.

If that is still too much copy-paste, you can consider defining an `ExchangeFilterFunction` to apply retry for every `WebClient` call automatically. Something like this:

```java
WebClient.builder()
     // ...
    .filter((request, next) -> next.exchange(request).retry()) // add full retry config here
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this and get back to you

Comment: @nobalG we're waiting ;)